# Iteratively renaming column names based on text and a value of a record in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

For a project, I received a really messy dataset and I attempt to get the data into a tidy format. Sample code below:

```
tbl <- 
  tibble(
  Col1 = c("Question", 2:5),
  Col2 = c("Value_1", "Value_2", "Value_3", "Value_4", "Value_5")
) %>% 
  spread(Col1, Col2) %>% 
  select(5, 1:4)
```

And it looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  Question `2`     `3`     `4`     `5`    
  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 Value_1  Value_2 Value_3 Value_4 Value_5
```

A got a lot of those colums, and renaming them one by one would be very tedious. So I'm trying to iteratively change the column names to a certain text (i.e, Question_Value_1) for every colname with for example something like `str_glue("Question {tbl %>% select(1) %>% pull(1)})`. However, I can't figure out how to do this iteratively with purrrr. So the desired output would be:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  Question_Value_1 Question_Value_2 Question_Value_3  Question_Value_4 Question_Value_5
  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 Value_1  Value_2 Value_3 Value_4 Value_5
```

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try `names(tbl) <- paste0('Question_value', seq(ncol(tbl)))`

Comment: @ Sotos: `seq(ncol(tbl))` will give just the values 1:n. However, I want to paste the value/text from the first row in the dataset! 1:5 could have been a:e for example and then `seq(ncol(tbl))` won't cut it.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't realise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out (thanks for the suggestions). This can be used in a dplyr chain.

```
tbl %>%
# method 1 str_glue
  set_names(str_glue("Question_{tbl %>% slice(1)}"))
# method 2 paste0
  set_names(paste0("Question", tbl %>% slice(1), sep = "_"))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this then,

```r
names(tbl) <- paste0("Question_", tbl[1,])

# or else
names(tbl) <- paste("Question", tbl[1,], sep = "_")
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# # A tibble: 1 x 5
# Question_Value_1 Question_Value_2 Question_Value_3 Question_Value_4 Question_Value_5
# <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
#   1 Value_1          Value_2          Value_3          Value_4          Value_5    
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Data

```r
tbl <- structure(list(Question = "Value_1", `2` = "Value_2", `3` = "Value_3", 
    `4` = "Value_4", `5` = "Value_5"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```